# How can i differnantiate newly updated rows in primefaces datatable on refresh?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with a list of events which gets refreshed with new events added to the list periodically. How can i differntiate the newly updated rows in datatable?? as we get in mails, i.e the new mail in inbox will be highlighted.

Comment: You could add a column to the `datatable` with wither a binary value (new/old) or a timestampt. Basically have a variable which you may use to determine how old the email is.

Comment: so you want me to store the flag variable in the datatabe?? Actually i dont store the list anywhere but i get the list from a rest service.

Comment: Or have a separate data base. But you need to store the information somewhere. Based on how accurate your classifications needs to be you may need to store more or less information. For example if the order of the dataset does not change, you could have a simple int variable where you could store the number of new `records/emails`. You could say that the last N=50 entries only are new and you wont have to store any extra information.

Comment: This question is as @Stanislav correctly points out, basically totally not PrimeFaces or even JSF related. It is 'architecture' on your side. What the best solution is, depends on your data (as Stanislav also correctly points out). So the only one who can answer this in the first place is you. Once you have the information, there are 100 options to display things: css, additional columns whatever...

Comment: sorry, actually this is my first post. I acutually need a sliding effect in datatable when ever datatable gets updated with new content and the newly added rows should be highlighted. Thank you Stanislav for a very quick reply.  I have to look at it if i can add a flag variable which can be stored.

Comment: Sliding and adding the new rows is not something that is supported by the PrimeFaces datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could highlight the new ones using the `rowStyleClass` of a datatable

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

But if you're using this option, you depend on an additional value with which you can check the dates, as Stanislav and Kukeltje said correctly.